# playing mp3 files located outside of public_html with soundmanager 2

Tags: php, mp3, soundmanager2

I have to stream some mp3 files located outside of public_html with soundmanager2 or any other flash-based mp3 player but i can't make it work.

Do you know any workaround on this subject ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a little php script which loads the content from the file and sends it. If your intention is to prevent the user from copying the sound this is probably not possible this way. If you just can't move the files to public_html you could create a symbolic link or just the php script.

You could use readfile like here:

```
header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="audio.mp3"');
readfile('../files/audio.mp3');
```

Comment: can you show me a little example for that php script ? thanks

Comment: i put the code in the answer, didn't know how to format here. The header calls are needed for the Browser or the player to know what filetype it is and the filename.